# CruiseControl.NET and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

Can the **sourcecontrol** block in CruiseControl.NET target TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CCNet is designed for using a subversion client of the form svn.exe rather than tortoisesvn directly (tortoisesvn has the svn client libraries compiled in).

In general the only advantage to using tortoisesvn automation commands is for handy dialogs for user interaction - typically with ccnet the last thing you want is anything that will raise a dialog.

Comment: do you have config sample for tortoise svn? it will help to understand the required changes.

Comment: I'm no longer using either tool but I'd be happy to try and answer if you can provide a little more detail about what you are looking for/trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

It can't use Tortoise specifically, but it can talk to Subversion.

More info [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/Using+CruiseControl+with+Subversion).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I think the anwser is: CC.NET can work with Subversion, take a look at: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Subversion+Source+Control+Block