# CruiseControl.net noob question on linking TortoiseSVN, other posts didn't help

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

Before giving me a link on StackOverflow on the [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420788/cruisecontrol-net-and-tortoisesvn) regarding this, I would like to apologize but that post didn't help me at all.

I'm looking more into detail on how I can really hook up TortoiseSVN to CruiseControl.net.

What I tried to do is to follow that post, but I got into a dead-end because I couldn't find the 
**net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.sourcecontrols.SVN** plugin from the SourceForge website. I tried scourging google but still got dead links.

Can anyone help me with this? I would appreciate it.

Comment: What purpose would there be to 'hook up' CC.net and TortoiseSVN? Do you actually mean an SVN server, or do you really mean you want CC.net to somehow 'hook up' with your local SVN *client*?

Comment: yes, andrew. can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can "hook up" CC.Net and TortoiseSVN.

CC.net is running on your build server, it needs a svn client to checkout and update source code. This must be a console client, not an interactive one like TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN is a plugin for windows explorer, it does not provide a client line client that could be use by CC.Net.

I am using CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client for the server client, you cand find it here : http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

 TortoiseSVN is used in the developers computers.